# fgets() crashs after a number of executions

Tags: c, fgets

I'm coding a program to crack the CRC16. I've been having some problems with outputting the file and keep the calculated CRC16(have no idea why it changes when I write it to a file). So what I'm doing here is read the input file, writing it to a output file with some gibberish and then I read the output file again and calculate it's CRC16. If it matches with the desired CRC16, then it is done. However after a bunch of executions the fgets() method crashes with a Seg fault.

Anyone could help me? Please ignore the performance issues, this is a test.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

        char outfile[strlen(argv[1])];
        strcpy(outfile,argv[1]);

        strcat(outfile,".crack");

        char crc16[5];
        strcpy(crc16,argv[2]);
        char newcrc16[5];
        char gebrish[80];
        char cat[2];
        int full = 1;
        int p = 0;
        int i,j,k;


        for(i=32; i< 128;i++)
                for(j=32; j< 128; j++)
                        for(k=32; k < 128; k++){
                                gebrish[0] =i;
                                gebrish[1] =j;
                                gebrish[2] =k;
                                gebrish[3] = '\n';
                                gebrish[4] ='\0';

                                boost::crc_16_type result;

                                FILE* file;
                                FILE* out;
                                char line[100];

                                printf("read out\n");
                                out = fopen(outfile,"w");

                                printf("read file\n");
                                file = fopen(argv[1],"r");
                printf("wrt\n");
                                while(fgets(line,80,file) != NULL){
                                        fputs(line,out);
                                }
                                fputs(gebrish,out);

                                fclose(file);
                                fclose(out);

                                printf("read gain\n");
                                out = fopen(outfile,"r");

                                while(fgets(line,80,out) != NULL){
                                        result.process_bytes(line,strlen(line));
                                        printf("%s",line);
                                }

                                int crc = result.checksum();

                                sprintf(newcrc16,"%x",crc);
                                printf("%s",newcrc16);

                                if(strcmp(crc16,newcrc16) == 0){

                                        printf("%s",gebrish);
                                        return 0;

                                }
                        }



        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which fgets crashes? 1st loop, 2nd loop or either?

Answer (score 1):

This causes a buffer overrun:

```
char outfile[strlen(argv[1])];
strcpy(outfile,argv[1]);

strcat(outfile,".crack");
```

as there is not enough space in `outfile` for terminating null character and `".crack"`. It will be overwriting memory it is not supposed to and *may* be the cause of the segmentation fault.

Change to:

```
    char outfile[strlen(argv[1]) + 1 + 6];
    strcpy(outfile,argv[1]);

    strcat(outfile,".crack");
```

Before accessing `argv` elements ensure they have been provided by checking `argc`:

```
if (argc > 2)
{
    /* Safe to use argv[1] and argv[2]. */
}
```

Check return values from `fopen()` also.

Comment: Thanks for the note on the buffer size. However the error is not there, I fixed the code(I guess the compiler was fixing it before) but it gives the same error and crashes in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely due to not checking the return value from open, and then calling fgets on a bad file.  Returns from system calls should always be checked if subsequent operations depend on them.  Even close can fail.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm testing it in a really controlled environment. The files will always be there. Anyway, it crashes after a bunch of execution of the loop, not in the first moment. Also, I need to know why it crashes, not how to avoid the crash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I tried to Read and Write from the same file in different moments without calling fclose() after the use. This way after some execution of the loop it crashes with a STATUS_VIOLATION. I have no idea why it didn't crash right away, but all I did was add a flcose() after reading the file for the CRC16 calculation.